# Self-referenced entity

Tags: spring-roo

I have an entity called **person**.
Each **person** has three fields :

sexe (male, female)
mother (self referenced to person)
father (self referenced to person)

Now, in my view jspx, I would like the two selected fields to only display female personn in the mother select and male personns in the father field. What would be the best way to do that ?

Comment: How is this question related to Spring Roo? I am tempted to flag and downvote!

Comment: First of all, my application is created with Spring roo, secondly,  I am new to Spring roo. I could easily perform this operation using other frameworks or languages but this question involves :
1- Creation of self-referencing entity in spring roo
2- Customization of a spring roo view and I guess modification of controlers too. Mabye the question is not clear enough ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should create dynamic finder to get persons by `sex`. Type in Roo console:

```
finder list
```

Then find something like `findPeopleBySex` and type:

```
finder add --finderName findPeopleBySex
```

If you don't want to scaffold this finder you can add `exposeFinders = false` to the `@RooWebScaffold` annotation of your `PersonController`.

Then you should open your `PersonController` (which body is empty I suppose) and place there something like the following:

```
@ModelAttribute("men")
public Collection<Person> populateMen() {
    return Person.findPeopleBySex(Gender.Male).getResultList();
}

@ModelAttribute("women")
public Collection<Person> populateWomen() {
    return Person.findPeopleBySex(Gender.Female).getResultList();
}
```

Finally open your `{project_root}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/people/create.jspx` then find the following lines:

```
    <field:select field="mother" id="c_xxx_Person_mother" itemValue="id" items="${people}" path="/people" z="xxx"/>
    <field:select field="father" id="c_xxx_Person_father" itemValue="id" items="${people}" path="/people" z="xxx"/>
```

And change them to be:

```
    <field:select field="mother" id="c_xxx_Person_mother" itemValue="id" items="${women}" path="/people" z="xxx"/>
    <field:select field="father" id="c_xxx_Person_father" itemValue="id" items="${men}" path="/people" z="xxx"/>
```

Make sure the value of `z` attribute (hash code) become `user-managed`. It means Roo will not change it in future.

Now you can run your application and see the result.

Comment: That is very classy. Thanks a lot Constantiner.